# Real integration to contour integration

Tags: real-analysis, contour-integration

I saw some similar questions in the website, namely [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/979326/use-contour-integration-to-calculate-real-integrals), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715311/using-contour-integration-to-solve-this-integral) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991566/how-to-use-contour-integration-to-compute-a-real-integral). What bothers me is that there is no general answer to this question:

When is it possible to transform a real integral to a contour integral? Always?

Or are there some requirements to satisfy, the shape of the function to integrate for example? And then, how do you decide the path to use?

I'm really confused about this. Can you point to any resource or keyword to search which may explain this in detail?

Comment: The semi-circle is a pretty common path, and it often modified to fit the problem.

Comment: expand, please :)

Comment: Well, for starts, well defined shapes are easier to integrate along.  That is only natural.  And out of all of the shapes, circles, or parts of circles, and straight lines, are the easiest to use thanks to $e^{i\theta}$

Comment: how does that fit to my question?

Comment: It helps the "how do you decide the path to use" part.  Also, branch cuts often play a role in the shape of the path.

Comment: I did some complex analysis, so I'm familiar with arcs and semicircles. I'm more interested in how you get a bean from a straight line and those kind of stuff - a bit more applied.

Comment: As I said, it often depends on branch cuts.  Poles also make a difference, and, of course, the function also makes a difference.  Notice that when we want to integrate along an undefined point, for example, we make a small circle to go around the point.  Beyond those thoughts, I say I have not dealt with much more.

Answer (score 4):

Most often when computing the real integral as a contour integral in the complex plane, one invokes [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma#Application_of_Jordan.27s_lemma).

$$C_R = \{R e^{i \theta} \mid \theta \in [0, \pi]\}$$
If the function $f$ is of the form
$$f(z) = e^{i a z} g(z) , \quad z \in C_R $$
then Jordan's lemma states the following upper bound for the contour integral:

$$\left| \int_{C_R} f(z) \, dz \right| \le \frac{\pi}{a} M_R \quad \text{where} \quad M_R := \max_{\theta \in [0,\pi]} \left| g \left(R e^{i \theta}\right) \right| .$$

If $f$ is continuous on the semicircular contour $C_R$ for all large R and

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} M_R = 0$$
then by Jordan's lemma
$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \oint_{C_R} f(z)\, dz = 0$$

Let $C=C_1\cup C_R$

where $C_1$ is the real line, and $C_R$ the half-circle.

We need

$$\oint_{C_R}f=0$$
for
$$\oint_{C}f=\oint_{C_1}f=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f$$

to hold, resulting in

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} f=2\pi i\sum\limits_{k=1}^nRes(f,z_k)$$

by residue theorem.

This is provided by Jordan's lemma in the limit as $R\to\infty$, assuming $\lim_{R \to \infty} M_R = 0$.

Comment: I understand I need to look more into Jordan Lemma. I will wait some other time, and if no other answers are posted I will mark this as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: @Novalink Think about it like this: $|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz|<\int_{C_R}|f(z)|dz<\int_{C_R}\max|f(t)|dz$

Answer (score 1):

You can always make contour integrals, but the real question is whether or not you can calculate anything out of it.  Often times, we follow the following path (pun intended):

$$P.V.\int_{\mathbb R}f(z)dz=\lim_{R\to\infty}\oint_Cf(z)dz-\int_{C_R}f(z)dz$$

where both integrals are taken counter clockwise, $C_R$ is the semi circle from $R$ to $-R$, and $C$ is the semi circle from $R$ to $-R$ plus a straight line from $-R$ to $R$, making $C$ a closed contour integral so that we may apply Cauchy's residue theorem.

Now, the goal is to have the scenario where

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}f(z)dz=0$$

And we can do so as follows:

$$\left|\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\right|\le\int_{C_R}|g(z)|dz\le\int_{C_R}\max_{t\in C_R}|g(t)|dz=\pi R\max_{t\in C_R}|g(t)|$$

which is simply saying that on the first step, we remove any possible chances for cancellations to occur.  To account for the direction of the integral, we let $f(z)=e^{iz}g(z)$.  Then, noting that the second integral is purely real, we can imagine that it must be less than or equal to it's maximum value integrated along the path.  Lastly, we realize that this simplifies down to the arc length multiplied by the maximum value.

Often times, it is easy to see that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\pi R\max_{t\in C_R}|g(t)|=0$$

which squeezes $\int_{C_R}f(z)dz\to0$ as $R\to\infty$.

Lastly, according to the residue theorem,

$$\oint_Cf(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{Res}(f,z_k)$$

where we evaluate over the singularities of $f$ where $\Im(z)\ge0$.  This gives us the principal value for our said integral.

Note that this does not always make much sense, since we could have

$$P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin(x)dx=0$$

when the integral doesn't exist.  So do be cautious of when to use.